# Repeating a function multiple time while changing its argument

Tags: python-3.x, function, dataframe, loops, pandas-groupby

I have a function which groups the rows of a df, according the value of a column "sup", and convert these groups into strings (for further processing).

| name | sup |
| --- | --- |
| mushroom | a |
| apples | a |
| flour | b |
| butter | b |
| sugar | c |
| salt | d |

```
def my_function(supplier):
 supplier_group = df.get_group(supplier)
 supplier_group.to_string()
 return supplier_group
```

The single argument for this function is the value I want to use to group by the rows

```
print(my_function('a'))
```

| name | sup |
| --- | --- |
| mushroom | a |
| apples | a |

```
print(my_function('b'))
```

| name | sup |
| --- | --- |
| flour | a |
| butter | a |

Now, I'd like to pass a list of values, Sup_list, as the argument of the function, and run the function multiple times so it iterate over the whole list, instead of having to manually enter the value every time.

This is the list I want to uses the function's argument

```
Sup_list = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I hope that makes sense and that I can get some help!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply recurse, appending the supplier data for each group to a list and then return that list.

Below is a simple recursion that achieves this.

```
import pandas as pd


def my_function(suppliers, res):
    if not suppliers:
        return res
    supplier_group = df.get_group(suppliers[0])
    res.append(supplier_group.to_string())
    my_function(suppliers[1:], res)
    return res


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['mushroom', 'apples', 'flour', 'butter', 'sugar', 'salt'],
    'sup': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}).groupby(['sup'])

sup_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

res = my_function(sup_list, [])
print(res)
for r in res:
    print(r)
```